# Gspread library returning [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, sockets, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, gspread

I made an app that autofills a spreadsheet in Python, using a library called gspread.
The code in which is uses credentials and loads up spreadsheets to grab data from has been consistently working without fail for months, until the last couple of days.

I've narrowed it down to a line thats: `datasheet = client.open(sheetnames["Datasheet"]).sheet1`
Once I run this line, everything falls apart.
The traceback goes into a socket.py file, which errors `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] get addrinfo failed`.

This one function keeps failing and the app is never allowed to make a connection, but keeps retrying until it exceeds the maximum amount of attempts allowed.

The erroring code doesn't originate from what I've written, but from a library. I don't know where to start to fix this, considering it worked fine before.

```
creds = ServiceAccountcredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
...in a class...in a function:
datasheet = client.open(sheetnames["Datasheet"]).sheet1
```

Comment: Personally, I have come across some issues with gspread recently and converted to google's official library which may be more work but more of a fix https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Comment: This has nothing to do with gspread, did you set a proxy on your system? Did you try to use the socket library and do a `socket.getaddrinfo("www.googkeapis.com", 443)` ? Or some other servers to confirm your python script can reach internet.